# Show identifiability issue given expression for model likelihood.

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, parameter-estimation

Equation below refers to the likelihood for my statistical model. I need to show the model has **identifiability** issues. The hint that I have been given is that I should attempt to interchange the parameters in the likelihood function.

$$
L(\alpha , \beta ; (x_{i}, .., x_{n})) = \left(\frac{\alpha \beta}{\beta-\alpha}\right)^{n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left((1-\alpha)^{r_i-1}-(1-\beta)^{r_{i}-1}\right)\
$$

**Edit:** explanation of model likelihood.

Graphical representation of the Markov chain:

[image]

The model is a discrete-time markov chain. Assume that we always start in state 1. $j$ is the time at which we observe being in state 2, and $r$ is the time at which we observe being in state 3.

The joint probability for one observation from this markov chain would be $$P(Y_{1}=y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n}=y_{n}) = (1-\alpha)^{i-1} \alpha (1-\beta)^{r-i-1}\beta$$

Now the issue is, that we can only observe $r$, the time at which we are in state 3. To marginalise out $i$, I think we would sum over all possible values of $i$.

\begin{align}
P(Y_{1}=y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n}=y_{n}) &= \alpha\beta\sum_{i=1}^{r-1} (1-\alpha)^{i-1}(1-\beta)^{r-i-1} 
\\&= \left(\frac{\alpha \beta}{\beta-\alpha}\right)\left((1-\alpha)^{r-1}-(1-\beta)^{r-1}\right)
\end{align}

Now we multiply each of the joint probability distributions $X_{1}, X_{2}, ..,X_{n}$ to form the likelihood that we have above.

**Note:** $0\leq\alpha, \beta \leq1$

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you know what identifiability means, then have you tried to apply the definition?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, a model that fails to be be identifiable has two parameters that appear to be equivalent to each other, based on what has been observed in the data. From this, I think if we substitute $\alpha = \beta$ and $\beta = \alpha$ into the model, the expression for the likelihood should be remain the same and hence the model has an issue with identifibility.

Comment: Could you explain how the likelihood is obtained?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, edited question. Please let me know if the explanation is clear.

Comment: Regarding the hint given, I don't see how $L(\alpha,\beta)=L(\beta,\alpha)$ holds for $\alpha\ne \beta$. If this holds then certainly you are done.